# Swing Notification like jquery notify

Tags: java, swing, noty

Is possible to make a floating notification on a java Swing GUI like [JQuery Noty](http://needim.github.io/noty/)?

Better if is possible with animations.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into the following https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases

I had worked it while my graduation, i think it might help you, its not look like jquery noty but it has more controls along with some animation.

examples for your reference:

http://www.dzone.com/links/r/swingx_tutorial_busy_label_jxbusylabel.html
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=240